# How to split multiple masks from a numpy array in single line?

Tags: python, numpy

I have a `500,500,3` shaped numpy array containing repetitive integer values. I can use `np.unique` to get unique integer values present in the said array (because they can be different for every such array).

Is there any way to split multiple masks in one line.

---

> Here **masks** is a numpy array. It contains different repetitive integer values

```
 ids = np.unique(masks) # ids = [0, 1, 2] for example
 # currently doing this
 mask0 = masks == ids[0]
 mask1 = masks == ids[1]
 mask2 = masks == ids[2]
```

Is there any single line method to get a set of all binary masks. For example something like.

```
 all_masks = masks == ids[:] # for example
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can broadcast both arrays to a shape of `(id, height, width, channels)`, and then check equality:

```
all_masks = (masks[np.newaxis] == ids[:, np.newaxis, np.newaxis, np.newaxis])
```

In the result, `all_masks[i]` is the `(height, width, channels)` binary mask for the `i`th id.